# LogLog Plot in MATLAB (Estimating PI, error vs N)

Tags: matlab, pi

TASK: Using the Monte_Carlo method, compute the approximation of PI for N=100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000,100000 and plot the Error of Approximation against N on a Log­Log Plot. Where Error=abs(Actual value­ - Approximate Value). In addition, compute PI using two other infinite series methods and compute pi for N=10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000. Plot out on the same graph the Error of Approximation on a Log­Log plot for all 2 formulae and the Monte­Carlo method.

```
Estimating PI using M_C Method.
clear all
clc
close all
%n = linspace(0, 100000, 100)
n = [100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 100000]


c = 0;
t = 0;

for q=1:length(n)
    x = rand([1 n(q)]);
    y = rand([1 n(q)]);

    for i= 1:n(q)
        t = t+1;
        if x(i)^2 + y(i)^2 <= 1
            c = c+1;
            figure(2)
            k(i) = x(i);
            r(i) = y(i);
            hold on;
        else 
            figure(2)
            p(i) = x(i);
            j(i) = y(i);

        end
end
figure(1)
hold on
if n(q) == 1000

    plot(k, r, 'b.');
    plot(p, j, 'r.');
end
ratio = c/t;
PI= 4*ratio
error = abs(pi - PI)
figure(2)
loglog(n(q), error, '-b');




end

loglog(n, error, 's-')
grid on

%% Calculating PI using the James Gregory

%n = 10000;
n = [10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]
d = 1;
c = 4;
for j = 1:n
    d = d + 2;
    c = c + ((-1)^(j))*(4)*(1/d);
end

PI_1 = c;
error = abs(n - PI_1);
loglog(n,error, '-s')
display(c);



%% Calculating PI using the Leibniz Formula for PI

%n = 10000;
n = [10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]
d = 1;
c = 1;

for k = 1:n
    d = d + 2;
    c = c + ((-1)^k)*(1/d);
end

PI_2 = c*4;
error = abs(n - PI_2);
figure(3)
loglog(n, error, '-s')
```

The problem I'm having is that the loglog plots don't display the expected information.

Comment: Probably the information is not correctly computed. I dont think the problem is with the loglog, do you?

Comment: Yes, your code works. Please brief on, what kind of plot you expected, what is the plot you get now, and any errors you get.

Comment: Well, when I run the code, I get what seems an infinite loop of Figures, I'm assuming because it's plotting it for all the values in n, yet, it doesn't seem to stop. I think what I want is for the figure to update as it progress through the values of the array 'n', and stop at the last value, yet at the same time plotting to the LogLog plot for the various values. Also, the Figure containing the Loglog plot doesn't render any points...

Answer (score 2):

### Plotting Discussion

For the Monte Carlo plotting, the line

```
loglog(n, error, 's-')
```

following the `for`-loop overwrites all of the plotting done by

```
loglog(n(q), error, '-b');
```

because a `hold('on')` was never issued for `figure(2)`.
Also, in both cases, the plots will look odd due both to the style options and the fact that `error` is not a vector:

- The call `loglog(n, error, 's-')` will generate a series of disconnected boxes since `n` is a vector and `error` is a scalar; Matlab interprets the elements of `n` as separated data sets each associated with the same scalar value `error` (the `error` from the last iteration of the `for`-loop; `plot([1,2],0,'s-')` is another example).
- The called `loglog(n(q), error, '-b');` has a similar problem.  Since the style calls for a "solid blue line" but the data passed to `loglog` is a scalar-scalar pair each iteration, nothing will appear.  Matlab cannot form a line for scalar-scalar input (consider the line plot `plot(1,1,'-b')` versus the circle plot `plot(1,1,'ob')` as another example).

These problems can be fixed by changing `error` to a vector of `length(n)`:

```
error = zeros(1,length(n)); % before for-loop
...
    error(q) = abs(pi - PI); % inside the q-for-loop
```

and performing the `loglog` plot *after* the `for`-loop only (this is also a performance increase since plotting calls are heavy relative to computation).

### Performance Discussion

Speaking of performance (to speed up your Monte Carlo), the crowning virtue of Monte Carlo integration, besides not succumbing to the [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality), is its ridiculously parallelizable (i.e., vectorizable) nature.

And this is a great thing since vanilla Monte Carlo requires a lot of samples to get accurate results.
Also, Matlab's [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) allows for a nice semantic way to pull values satisfying a number of criteria.

With that said, your `i`-`for`-loop for the Monte Carlo method can be vetorized with the following code:

```
% % ----- i-for-loop replacement

%   Determine location of points
inCircle = (x.^2 + y.^2) <= 1;

%   k = xIn, r = yIn
xIn = x(inCircle);
yIn = y(inCircle);

%   p = xOut, j = yOut
xOut = x(~inCircle);    % or x(not(inCircle));
yOut = y(~inCircle);    % or y(not(inCircle));

% % ----- end of i-for-loop replacement

%   Calculate MC pi and error
ratio    = nnz(inCircle)/n(q);
PI       = 4*ratio;
error(q) = abs(pi - PI);
```

Comment: Thanks TroyHaskin. I'm going to attempt to make the modifications which you recommended. If I run into any problems, would it be okay to come back to you for further questions?